# Firefox not displaying WebVTT captions on video

Tags: html, firefox, video

I have a basic example of using [the track element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track) to load captions. In Firefox, the captions render sometimes, but not other times. Things that I have checked:

1. CSS positioning of video element (still see the issue with no positioning change)
2. Opening a private window (sometimes makes them show)
3. Disabling cache
4. CORS headers of mp4/vtt server (they are set to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`) and the video tag has `crossorigin="anonymous"`
5. Changing `autoplay` and `muted` attributes

Reproduced intermittently in Firefox versions 97.0 and 98.0b4. I haven't noticed this issue in other browsers.

*Edit:* I added some CSS to this snippet that makes the issue repro for me now. So it's pointing to CSS, but weirdly, once I reproduce it, the captions continue to remain hidden even when I remove all styles.

```css
.modal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.video-wrap {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 480px;
  position: relative;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}

::cue {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <h1>Video w/ VTT</h1>
  <div class="video-wrap">
    <video controls muted crossorigin="anonymous">
      <source
        src="https://cuttle-learning.netlify.app/onboarding-sketch/videos/onboarding2.mp4?cachebreak=001"
        type="video/mp4"
      />
      <track
        label="English"
        kind="captions"
        srclang="en"
        src="https://cuttle-learning.netlify.app/onboarding-sketch/videos/onboarding2.vtt?cachebreak=001"
        default=""
      />
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: captions working on left, not working on right]

Demo also here: https://h05uh.csb.app/

Comment: For me, this snippet _is_ showing the captions in Firefox (97)

Comment: Yeah, me too. This is partially to list the _potential_ fixes I have found in various SO posts and bugzilla.

Comment: I added some CSS that makes the issue repro in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1733232

> That's currently the most minimal example I have which consistently
> fails. Some (basic) examples fail after a couple of reloads. I assume
> that's because of caching and layout complexity.